# Rocket Universe Dictionary passing VM attribute value to subroutine

Tags: dictionary, universe, rocket

Okay this might get a tad complex or not.

Have a file with a multivalues in attribute 4

I want to write another dictionary item that loops through the multivalue list, calls a subroutine and returns calculated values for each item in attribute 4.

somthing like

<4> a]b]c]d]e

New attribute

@RECORD<4>;SUBR("SUB.CALC.AMT", @1)

Result

<4>             AMT
a               5.00
b              15.00
c              13.50
d               3.25

Not quite sure how to pass in the values from RECORD<4>, had a vague notion of a @CNT system variable, but that's not working, which might mean it was from SB+ or one of the other 4GLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be over thinking this.

You should just be able to reference it without out doing the ";" and @1 thing (I am not familiar with that convention). Using an I-Descriptor this should do the trick, though I have traditionally used the actual dictionary names instead of the @RECORD thing.

```
 SUBR("SUB.CALC.AMT", @RECORD<4>)
```

This should work provided your subroutine is compiled, cataloged and returns your desired value with the same value/subvalue structure as @RECORD<4> in the first parameter of the Subroutine.

```
SUBROUTINE SUB.CALC.AMT(RETURN.VALUE,JUICY.BITS)
JBC = DCOUNT(JUICY.BITS<1>,@VM)
FOR X=1 TO JBC
   RETURN.VALUE<1,X> = JUICY.BITS<1,X>:" or something else"
NEXT X
RETURN
END
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Van, exactly right, not sure why I got caught on the place holder logic. Basically needed to derive a model (RECORD<4>) cost which included a subvalued extra cost depending on country, ergo the subroutine call.